# How to apply class for any control type in div?

Tags: asp.net, css, class, styles

In my forms has many `<asp:Label>`, I want apply Height for all there, but I not want set height one by one

Is possible set they height by a class in it parent div?

```
<div class="FormContent">
    <h1 class="title">Cadastro de Cliente</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:Label Text="Nome" Height="10px" runat="server" CssClass="h4" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Nome" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Ex: João da Silva Cunha" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:Label Text="Logradouro" Height="10px" runat="server" CssClass="h4" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Logradouro" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Ex:Rua D'Pedro II" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:Label Text="Número" Height="10px" runat="server" CssClass="h4" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Numero" CssClass="form-control" Width="80px" placeholder="Ex:100" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want set "Height='10px'" for all <asp:Label>, can I set it with a class apply in parent div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Height="10px"` from all label controls. Label is rendered as a SPAN in browser so you can do it in a single class:

```
div.FormContent span {
   height:10px;
}
```

This will set the height for all labels within the content DIV.

**Update**

I see your labels have a class of their own assigned - you can add the height directly to `h4` class as an alternative

```
.h4 {
   /* your other styles */
   height:10px;
}
```

If you want to affect only `h4` within content DIV you can do

```
div.FormContent .h4 {
   height:10px;
}
```

Or even to tighten it up completely

```
div.FormContent span.h4 {
   height:10px;
}
```

Comment: Is possible I set CssClass="myClass" for all Label in this div of once?

Comment: You already have a class assigned to your labels "h4" - you can reuse it. Or you can add a new class `CssClass="h4 myClass"` to all of them if needed